# Expand cells by horizontal order?

Tags: java, html, orbeon, xforms

How can we expand cells in grid by horizontal position? It will be nice to expand two Output Text cells in one.

Comment: Can you provide more information or some examples or some pictures of expected output

Comment: @KaipaMSarma, sure. A couple of precision: Imagine you have a table with 2x3 dimension ( 2 rows, 3 columns). Suppose I want to expand 2-nd and 2-rd cell of first row. So, after expanding columns you will have a table with 2 cells in first row, and 3 cells on the second row. It's like `COLSPAN="2"` in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, expanding cell horizontally (`colspan`) isn't supported in Form Builder. Only expanding cell vertically (`rowspan`) is supported.

You could update the source of the form to add a `colspan` where necessary, and remove unnecessary `xh:td`, but I wouldn't recommend doing it: since Form Builder doesn't take those `colspan` in account, it is likely to break the structure of your table when you later add/remove columns or extend cells vertically.